# Factoring out $4x^3+2x^2y-2xy^2-y^3$

Tags: polynomials, factoring, multivariate-polynomial

This can be factored as follows:

$$4x^3+2x^2y-2xy^2-y^3 = (2x^2-y^2)(2x+y)$$

What is a systematic way for finding this factorization?

Comment: It is equivalent to finding the roots of $4X^3-2X^2+2X-1=0$, since the expressions equals $y^3(4X^3-2X^2+2X-1)$ where $X=x/y$.

Comment: You might try $x=10,y=1$, and factor $4200-21$  That might give extra factors ( in this case,3 and 7) that don't work for all $x$ and $y$, but in this case it gives $21$ that does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{gather*}
4x^{3} +2x^{2} y-2xy^{2} -y^{3}\\
=\left( 4x^{3} -2xy^{2}\right) +\left( 2x^{2} y-y^{3}\right)\\
=2x\left( 2x^{2} -y^{2}\right) +y\left( 2x^{2} -y^{2}\right)\\
=( 2x+y)\left( 2x^{2} -y^{2}\right)
\end{gather*}
Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$$4x^3-2xy^2=2x(2x^2-y^2)$$

$$2x^2y-y^3=y(2x^2-y^2)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: is that systematic?

Comment: @Kenta, What is your definition of systematic?

Comment: The systematic explanation for this working is above

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I am not sure, but the author uses the term "systematic."

Answer (score 2):

The systematic way here is whenever you have a sum of 4 terms, you can check to see if factor by grouping works.    In a sum of the form $a+b+c+d$,   factor by grouping works if and only if $ad=bc$.  If it does,  then you pull out the greatest common factor of $a$ and $b$.   When you do so, you will be GUARANTEED to be able to pull a factor out of $c+d$ to match the binomial you got when factoring out $a+b$, as in lab's answer above.